# Can I add additional fields to vnd.error?

Tags: rest, spring-hateoas, hateoas

In Spring HATEOAS, you can return a `VndError` object that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "logref" : "some request id",
    "message" : "your request was incorrect."
  }
]
```

The [mime type specification](https://github.com/blongden/vnd.error) mentions some optional and required fields, but does not talk about adding additional fields.

If I were to extend the `vnd.error` payload to look like this:

```
[
  {
    "logref" : "some request id",
    "message" : "your request was incorrect.",
    "additional" : {
      "some" : "additional",
      "payload" : "fields"
    }
  }
]
```

Is the format still valid according to the specification?

Comment: what would the additional fields do that the spec doesn't let you do?

Comment: Add more information about the exception. The `logref` field allows for a unique request ID, but we could append a more complex `diagnostics` object too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no mention of the equivalent of `xsd:any` (documented [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_any.asp)). i.e. there doesn't appear to be a way to extend the schema. If it's just one client that you control then you could 'fork' the schema and add additional stuff the client will know exists. However, if any client can access it and is expecting a `vnd.error`, which is what it expects if it sees `application/vnd.error+json` and if it doesn't ignore unknown attributes in its parser it could fail to parse and not even get the error.

Plus if a client doesn't care about the error but wants a `Retry-After` header instead, then the request will contain stuff not required.

Can you create a new endpoint `/logref/` perhaps? The client can send the `vnd.error` `logRef` and get more info and you can send whatever you need back in that as it won't be a `vnd.error` response.

Ultimately, logRef is for the server side. Any client would only be interested in displaying the message to its user and the logRef should they wish to follow up the error but I suspect a ThreadLocal error may not make any sense to a client. The content pointed to by logRef would only make sense to the server.

Indeed, exposing implementation details to a client via a ThreadLocal error could be a security concern. Internal server errors should be verbose enough for the server developers to fix the issue and being verbose relies on clients not seeing those errors, which could contain sensitive implementation details.

Comment: Thank you, I was indeed wondering if parsers would be able to handle these additions. Adding a new endpoint would mean that we have to store the diagnostics object, when it is merely an ephemeral piece of information that is a `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: I've added a note about security if sending ThreadLocal errors